# How do I set a value to a variable by passing the variales name in C?

Tags: c, variables, pointers

```
char whatVar[] = "";

float phValue, ecValue, tempValue;
```

I am not sure if this is possible or not in C. Each of the float values will be set randomly.  I would like to set their values depending on what the char whatVar corresponds to.  For example, lets say `char whatVar[] = "phValue";`  How do I point to the variable name inside whatVar to then set the value?  I would like to achieve this without using if conditionals or a switch.

Comment: +1 interesting question , nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

Don't; use an array. Tying your program logic to the names of your variables is a horrible idea.  Variable names exist to help you as a programmer reason about what the code is doing.  Beyond that the do not (and should not) have any significance.

Instead, use a collection where the index/bucket/mapping/whatever has logical meaning.  It is very common for beginners to do exactly as you want to do, but it is almost certainly a bad idea.  Sounds to me like you want a string -> float map or hash table.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to implement the translation of `whatVar` onto the actual variable value *manually*. C language has no such immediate feature.

It can be done by `if/switch` ladder. Or it can be done by pre-building a table that "projects" (maps) variable names to variable addresses (and, if necessary, types). You will have to manually search through the table. It will still have `if`'s though, unless you develop some sort of [minimal] perfect hashing function for your names (see Steve Jessop's comment).

Comment: You can do it without ifs/switches/ternaries if you construct a condition-free expression that evaluates to (for example) `0` when the input is `'p'`, `1` when it is `'e'` and `2` for `'t'`. Evaluate that expression for `*whatVar`, then have a 3-element lookup array which gives you a pointer to the variable you want. Obviously this doesn't do any checking of its input, that's going to be much harder without conditions. And as ever, this kind of branch-avoidance is a pinhole optimization-attempt that probably won't help, it's just what the questioner asked for.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Yes, some sort of perfect hash would work. But I'm sure this is not the objective behind the OP's requirement.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, that sounds really interesting.  I am as new as new can get with C.  I started using C because it's required for the Arduino electronics board.  Ram is also limited on the Arduino, so I think using a hash would require a lot of ram.  I will most likely resort to using conditionals.

Comment: For example `(x / 3) % 3` has the property that the x-values `'p'`, `'e'` and `'t'` have different outputs, assuming ASCII. So you could use that to distinguish between the valid inputs, it just won't tell you whether or not the string really is the name of one of your variables. There's probably a faster "hash function" that will do it with a shift and a mask, that's just the first I came up with. It's a hack, but then you asked for a hack ;-)

Answer (score 1):

why not ?

```
if(strcmp(whatVar, "phValue") == 0)
{
   phvalue = 3; //some value
}
```

and so on and so forth.

Edit : if the `if`s and the `switch` is not desired then we can use some sort of stl `map` ing between the string representations as the keys and their variables as the values.

Comment: Note this is how most of us interpret the `argv`'s with `argc`s !!!! either with a `switch` of an `if`

Comment: @lc, OP doesn't want if conditionals.

Comment: @jsn That's embarassing, I didn't see that. Still not sure what's so bad about a little if statement though.

Comment: @lc There is nothing wrong with using a little if statement.  I was attempting to try something different.

Answer (score 1):

This is outside of the language specification and I think if this is a feature that you wish to have in the language another language would be of more use to you that has this kind of functionality in it.

The only way I can think of implementing this is by doing some preprocessing tricks, which just seems like a bad idea. With this method you will not have if's in the code it self but some very unmaintainable preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

If you really really want to do this, you can use the `dlsym` function (as long as the variables you are accessing are global).  Here's a quick example:

```
 #include <dlfcn.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 float phValue, ecValue, tempValue;  
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    phValue = 0;
    ecValue = 0;
    tempValue  = 0;
    printf("Before:\n");
    printf("\tphValue = %f\n", phValue);
    printf("\tecValue = %f\n", ecValue);
    printf("\ttempValue  = %f\n", tempValue);

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i += 2) {
       float *varptr = (float *)dlsym(RTLD_MAIN_ONLY, argv[i]);
       *varptr = atof(argv[i+1]);
    }
    printf("\nAfter:\n");
    printf("\tphValue = %f\n", phValue);
    printf("\tecValue = %f\n", ecValue);
    printf("\ttempValue  = %f\n", tempValue);
 }
```

And a demo:

```
 % gcc varname.c -ldl
 % ./a.out phValue 12.1 tempValue 4.3 ecValue 2.2
 Before:
    phValue = 0.000000
    ecValue = 0.000000
    tempValue  = 0.000000

 After:
    phValue = 12.100000
    ecValue = 2.200000
    tempValue  = 4.300000
```